# Why is a branch not displayed in Msysgit?

Tags: git, msysgit

I have a branch called "develop" in my repository (as confirmed by `git branch -a`). However, I do not see it in the history view of Msysgit.

Is there something special about this branch that causes it to not show? How can I diagnose/correct this?

Answer (score 0):

A `git log --branches` would show all the branches, even if your current branch isn't "`develop`".

Similarly, with `gitk` (included in msysgit), you can call that GUI with the `--branches` option.